# socket.gethostbyname giving wrong IP

Tags: python, sockets, ip, gethostbyname

`socket.gethostbyname("vidzi.tv")` giving `'104.20.87.139'`

ping `vidzi.tv` gives `'104.20.86.139'`

`socket.gethostbyname("www.vidzi.tv")` giving `'104.20.87.139'`

ping `www.vidzi.tv` gives `'104.20.86.139'`

Why socket.gethostbyname is giving wrong IP for this website? It is giving right IP for other websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any "wrong" IPs in your question. A DNS server is allowed to return multiple IP addresses for the same host. The client generally just picks one of them. A lot of servers use this as a part of their load balancing, as clients select any available server and since they generally would pick different ones the traffic gets split up evenly. Your `ping` command and your `gethostbyname` command are just selecting different available IPs, but neither is "wrong".

You can see all the IPs that are returned for a given hostname with a tool like `nslookup` or `dig`.